# How does SVM deal with the case of multiple perfect separators?

Tags: svm, algorithms

I couldn't find a specific answer to this.

It's a general query I have, no specific code attached.

Is it possible for there to be more than one perfect line/hyperplane separating two (or more) classes in support vector machines?

If there is, the best dividing line randomly chosen? Or is it unlikely there would be more than one?

Answer (score 0):

SVM chooses the separator with the widest "parallel" margin

So for example, given the choice between pink, orange and green margins separating the circles and squares in the example illustrated  below, it will choose green (in effect a line midway between the two green margin lines shown)

[image]